# Usage of apostrophe in this sentence

Tags: apostrophe, quotation-marks

As per this statement, Does the usage of apostrophe looks correct?

> Thanks to "abc news" for this broadcast of memorable gathering of late CEO with his employees.

Comment: Where is the apostrophe?

Comment: If you mean to ask if the double-quotes are ok, they are not.  Also,  “of memorable gathering” and “of late CEO” are grammatically wrong (missing articles).  Also,  “As per this statement” means  “According to this statement”, which is semantically inappropriate. (In some circumstances, “as per” may act like “with regard to”, but not here.) Also, you may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: This reads like a stereotypical translation by a Japanese speaker. I guess Japanese doesn't have an equivalent of _the_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more correct way to write this would be:

> Thanks to ABC News for this broadcast of a memorable gathering of the late CEO with his employees.

*ABC News* is a proper name, so it is capitalized, not quoted. And there should be articles before *memorable gathering* and *late CEO*.